# Opencv c++: error: 'it' does not name a type

Tags: c++, opencv

This code runs perfectly on windows but i am trying to run this on linux and it gives this error:

> In function ‘void kmline(cv::Mat, std::vector >&)’:|
>   error: ‘it’ does not name a type| error: expected‘;’ before ‘it’|
>   error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope| ||=== Build failed: 3
>   error(s), 0
>
> > warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|

**code:**

```
void kmline( Mat image, std::vector<Point>& points )

{.
.
.
.
    if (points.size() > 1) //we have 2 points
        {

            for (auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
            {


            }
        }

}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using GNU GCC Compiler.

Comment: Check your version with `gcc -v`

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11` flag?

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk , no just using -g option, in codeblock

Comment: Add the flag I mentioned please. I believe you are able to choose standart somewhere in codeblocks though.

Comment: hi, compile with g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui   and add using namespace cv; using namespace std; and include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> <vector>  that works for me.

Comment: @Lukasz Daniluk, thanks it worked with the -std=c++11 flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compile with `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui`   and add using namespace cv; using namespace std; and include    that works for me.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void kmline( Mat image, std::vector<Point>& points )

{
  if (points.size() > 1) //we have 2 points                                                                                                                                     
    {

      for (auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
        {


        }

    }
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```